# What is the difference between GetMem and AllocMem?

Tags: delphi, memory, allocation

In Delphi, I see several similar functions that can be used to allocate memory, such as GetMem and AllocMem. What are the differences between them?

I read the document and only find that GetMem will not initialize the memory after allocation, while AllocMem does.

Then whether I need to initialize the memory after calling GetMem? The doc says yes. But I see in some Delphi source code they do not call Initialize.

And whether I need to finalize the memory after finishing using it? I see in some Delphi source codes, they do, but somethings they don't do.

Thanks

Comment: Kind of a strange question given that you provide the answer in the text of your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Logic seems simple - if you need zero-initialized buffer, you can use `AllocMem`.

If you fill buffer with own data in any case, and never use default contents - you can use `GetMem`.

Answer (score 5):

The difference is that `AllocMem` fills the newly allocated buffer with zeros, while `GetMem` doesn't. If your code requires the newly allocated buffer to be all-zeros initially, you can use `AllocMem` instead of manually writing zeroes in the buffer; if you don't care about the initial bytes in the buffer, you can do a (probably) cheaper `GetMem`.

For example,

```
var
  p: PByte;
begin
  GetMem(p, 1024);
  try
    p^ := 20;
    (p + 1)^ := 30;
    (p + 2)^ := p^ + (p + 1)^;
    ShowMessage((p + 2)^.ToString);
  finally
    FreeMem(p);
  end;
end;
```

is valid and will always display `50`, but

```
GetMem(p, 1024);
try
  p^ := 20;
  (p + 2)^ := p^ + (p + 1)^;
  ShowMessage((p + 2)^.ToString);
finally
  FreeMem(p);
end;
```

can display anything -- it all depends on what byte happened to be at `p + 1` at the time the code was executed (chance).

If you start by filling your buffer with zeroes, as in

```
GetMem(p, 1024);
try
  FillChar(p^, 1024, 0);
  p^ := 20;
  (p + 2)^ := p^ + (p + 1)^;
  ShowMessage((p + 2)^.ToString);
finally
  FreeMem(p);
end;
```

you are guaranteed to see `20`, since `p + 1` will hold `0`.

As an alternative, you could do

```
p := AllocMem(1024);
try
  p^ := 20;
  (p + 2)^ := p^ + (p + 1)^;
  ShowMessage((p + 2)^.ToString);
finally
  FreeMem(p);
end;
```

since the documentation guarantees that `AllocMem` sets every byte in the newly-allocated buffer to `0`.

But of course, allocating memory manually on the heap is for ("advanced") low-level stuff; most often, you don't do that. If you do that, you should be aware of things like [internal data formats](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Internal_Data_Formats_(Delphi)).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your need. Do you need just a buffer and won't care what it has initially? Use GetMem.

> GetMem allocates a block of the given Size on the heap, and returns
>   the address of this memory in parameter P. The bytes of the allocated
>   buffer are not set to zero. To dispose of the buffer, use FreeMem. If
>   there isn't enough memory available to allocate the block, an
>   EOutOfMemory exception is raised.
>
> Note: If the memory needs to be zero-initialized, use AllocMem
>   instead.

If your logic expects all the bytes of that buffer set to be zero, use AllocMem.

> AllocMem allocates a block of the given Size on the heap, and returns
>   the address of this memory. Each byte in the allocated buffer is set
>   to zero. To dispose of the buffer, use FreeMem. If there isn't enough
>   memory available to allocate the block, an EOutOfMemory exception is
>   raised.
>
> Note: If the memory does not need to be zero-initialized, it is more
>   efficient to use GetMem instead.

**//And whether I need to finalize the memory after finishing using it?**
When talking about allocation of memory generally, the memory you allocate should always be freed.

There are few exceptions to this -

- When your objects are reference counted
- When another object takes care of an object and freeing it up

Comment: Thank you. I just notice there are Initialize and Finalize procedures for initialize & finalize the buffer. When should I invoke Finalize procedure?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to call `Finalize`? What exactly needs to be finalized? For arrays you use dynamic arrays and they are finalized automatically. If you have to use dynamic allocation for records, you use `New` and `Dispose` and so have them finalized. Why are you even calling `GetMem` or `AllocMem`? Nobody can offer guidance without a clear understanding of the context?

Comment: I don't much care for this answer, because of the final part. Any memory manually allocated must be manually deallocated. You say, "there are few exceptions", but that's not true. There are no exceptions. If you allocate with `GetMem` or `AllocMem`, then you must call `FreeMem`. If you allocate with `New` then you must call `Dispose`. Reference counted things like strings, dynamic arrays, interfaces, anon methods, etc. are not allocated using `GetMem` or `AllocMem` or `New`. As for transferring ownership, that's somewhat orthogonal. That simply delegates the responsibility.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I was talking in the last part in more general sense than only AllocMem or GetMem

Comment: That's not really terribly clear though, and the question is explicit in being about manual memory allocation. Perhaps some of the lack of clarity is actually a result of the question talking about finalization. I don't think that the asker means deallocation when he says finalization. I think he means finalization in terms of managed types. But if we are going to talk of managed types, then that should be made explicit in the question, and further, managed types should not be allocated with `GetMem` or `AllocMem`.